# Animation Breaks when Exporting to unity

Tags: animation, unity

im tyring to Export an Simple animation to unity, the animations is made out of 5 meshes, and created using only keyframes, but when im in unity, the model itself isnt right, some of the meshes move out of their place and others render differently than in blender.

and the animation for some reason is broken too, instead of playing all together, it aplied every string of keyframes to every mesh individually, and and even to meshes which its even their animation.

any way i could fix it?

[image]

[image: Original Model]

i dont know how to upload gifs, So i didnt upload the animation problem..

Comment: Did you apply (Ctrl A) Loc rot and scale of every object before exporting?

Comment: Yes I did, i think theres a chance i know why is it, Can you export animations that dont contain Rigging? I made the animation by moving the object and adding keyframes, Can you upload that to unity?